# Tensorflow equivalent of numpy.random.normal

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to add a Gaussian noise to output of each activation layer in a Keras pre-trained imagenet. I am inserting a custom layer after every activation layer. In this custom layer, I want to add a Guassian noise with stddev as a percentage of the input tensor.
In numpy, if I have a stddev matrix stddev_dist, I will generate random Gaussian noise as

```
guass_noise = np.random.normal(scale = stddev_dist, size=stddev_dist.shape)
```

How to do equivalent of this to the input tensor in a custom layer.
stddev_dist_tensor = tf.abs(input) * 0.02  (stddev= 2% of input tensor)

Can somebody help with generating gaussian noise for stddev_dist_tensor ?

Comment: [`tf.random.normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal) ?

Comment: Hi ! Can you check out this two links on adding Gaussian noise in custom layers. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842958/keras-gaussiannoise-layer-no-effect     https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89663/keras.layers.GaussianNoise    https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GaussianNoise?hl=it

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution to gaussian noise in between keras layers**

```
import tensorflow as tf
stddev=0.02
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(128,128,3))
gaus        = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev,name='output')(input_layer)
model       = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=gaus)
```